# Vim: customize tex equation highlight

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, tex

How do I force vim to highlight the following environment:

```
\begin{dmath*}
  2 + 2
\end{dmath*}
```

the same way as

```
\begin{equation*}
 2 + 2
\end{equation*}
```

?

i.e I want the `dmath` environments (in its plain and starred versions) to be highlighted the same ways as the `equation` (plain and starred) environment.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I pasted your question into Vim, `:setf tex`, and then used the [SyntaxAttr.vim - Show syntax highlighting attributes of character under cursor](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=383) plugin to find out that the corresponding syntax group name is `texMathZoneES`.

Then I opened `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/tex.vim` and searched for it. I didn't find that directly, but something like this:

```
call TexNewMathZone("E","equation",1)
```

Then I looked up `:help ft-tex-syntax` (completed from the command-line via `<C-D>`), and found under `:help tex-math` a nice documentation. With that, I created the following solution:

```
call TexNewMathZone("M","dmath",1)
```

You can put that into `~/.vim/after/syntax/tex.vim`, as suggested, to make it permanent. Easy, isn't it?!